# I'm getting non-nullable instance in dart how can I fix it?

Tags: flutter, dart

here is my code

```
 void main() {
    user userOne=user('silver',19);
    print(userOne.name);
    superUser userTwo=superUser('sasha',1);
    print(userTwo.name);
 }

 class user{
  int age;
  String name;
  user(String name,int age){
    this.name=name;
    this.age=age;
  }
  void login(){
    print("user has logged in");
  }
}
class superUser extends user{
  superUser(String name,int age):super(name,age);
  
  void publish(){
    print("publish update");
  }
}
```

I'm getting these errors though I initialized the variables in the constructor.

```
Non-nullable instance field 'name' must be initialized.
Non-nullable instance field 'age' must be initialized.
```

should I initialize the integer variable to 0 and string variable to empty string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
 void main() {
    user userOne=user('silver',19);
    print(userOne.name);
    superUser userTwo=superUser('sasha',1);
    print(userTwo.name);
 }

 class user{
  int age;
  String name;
  // Syntactic sugar for setting name and age
  // before the constructor body runs.
  user(this.name, this.age);
   
  void login(){
    print("user has logged in");
  }
}
class superUser extends user{
  superUser(String name,int age):super(name,age);
  
  void publish(){
    print("publish update");
  }
}
```

Also it's better to use UpperCamelCase for class names, meaning `User`, `SuperUser` instead of `user`, `superuser`.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use non-nullable properties before initalizing. So, you have 2 option:

1- Declare late variables.

```
class user{
  late int age;
  late String name;
  user(String name,int age){
    this.name=name;
    this.age=age;
  }
  void login(){
    print("user has logged in");
  }
}
```

2- Make nullable.

```
class user{
      int? age;
      String? name;
      user(String name,int age){
        this.name=name;
        this.age=age;
      }
      void login(){
        print("user has logged in");
      }
    }
```

Comment: I got it. thank you for your response. it was useful.